# one of two fields or both with validation and a response

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have been trying to do an either or both form validation with a response.
The `main.js` is...

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["cart"]["qty1"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="Adult"){
        alert("Select Either an Adult or Child Quantity, or Both");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["cart"]["qty2"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="Child"){
        alert("Select Either an Adult or Child Quantity, or Both");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["cart"]["product1[]month"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="Select Date"){
        alert("Select Date");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["cart"]["product1[]time"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="Time"){
        alert("Select Time");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["cart"]["product1[]hotel"].value;

    if (x==null|| x=="Hotel or Cruise Ship"){
        alert("Hotel or Cruise Ship must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

`qty1` and `qty2` need to be an either or both, just not empty and I have not been able to get it to work right. The code above is original code and not formatted to do the either or both.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Comment: not the cause, but `x==null` cant happen. if `x` is a form input, and empty string is what you'd get if empty